# List all lines that do no contain a number using grep

Tags: grep

Trying to list all lines that do not contain a number in a file:

> grep -v '[^0-9]' filename

Doesn't seem to work as I thought it would.

This is the file:

```
 UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD   
root          1     0  0 Oct16 ?        00:01:15 /sbin/init   
root                                          root   
root        10     2  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:02 [migration/0]  
root20   
t90hch1    478   442  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 sshd:t90hch1@pts/3   
support  

T90hch1    488   478  0 13:24 pts/3    00:00:00 -bash   
root20     498     1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan   root       730  1498  0 13:27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: z1746903 [priv]   
z1J46903   763    48  0 13:27 ?        00:00:00 rooot: z1746903@pts/18   z4746903   764   763  0 13:27 pts/18   00:00:00 -bash   
root      1492     1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:32 /usr/sbin/testooooo   
daemon    1493   408  1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f   
zY6A7846  1716 24089  0 13:35 pts/41   00:00:00 nano +183 Assign5.cpp   
z1746903  1751   764  0 13:35 pts/18   00:00:00 nano   
z1234567  1799   888                            bAsh   
r78959j1   499                                  BUSH
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are inverting the match, you need to first start with an expression which returns the lines you *don't* want (`[0-9]`), then invert it:

```
grep -v '[0-9]' filename
```

Comment: Oh man, it was that easy. I feel dumb that it's taken me this long looking at it and then asking for help to realize that's what it was.

Comment: @DanWhalen No problem, If you found this useful, pehaps accept the answer?